# @ (or "at sign") is ending my MySQL query early, resulting in error

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on my first login script. I have been following examples from a book, but this is where I am stuck. I want the user login to be an e-mail address, but when I would hit submit, I would get this error.

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\mysite\index.php on line 19
```

The script works from the book, there's no typos, and from Google, I found that error is given if the original query fails, so I decided to insert a "mysqli_error" to check what is wrong and I got this:

```
Nah. admin@mysite.comYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@mysite.com AND password = SHA('password')' at line 1
```

So, I am almost positive that the @ sign is ending my query early. I have trim and mysql_real_escape_string as a way to clean up the strings, but besides that I have nothing. I have been Googling for a while now and I can't find or figure out how to make an exception for the @ ("at sign") or some kind of work around.

I didn't want this question to be too long or complicated, but I can provide more code if needed.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Here is the complete code to narrow down the solution.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $loginEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['loginEmail']));
    $loginPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['loginPassword']));        

    $query = "SELECT user_id, username FROM user_db WHERE email = $loginEmail AND password = SHA('$loginPassword')";
    $loginData = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($loginData) == 1) {
        echo 'You win!';
    }

    else {
        $error = mysqli_error($dbc);
        echo 'Nah. ' . $loginEmail . $error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you surround the email address with quotes in your query? BTW: Showing your query could really help identifying the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals need to be in single-quotes:

```
...WHERE email = 'accountname@example.com' AND password = SHA('password')
```

The `mysql_real_escape_string()` function adds backslashes to special characters within your variable's content, but it does *not* delimite the string with single-quotes.

For example:

```
$loginEmail = "O'Reilly";
$loginEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($loginEmail);
```

Now the content of $loginEmail is:

```
O\'Reilly
```

Not:

```
'O\'Reilly'
```

So you need to add the quotes in your SQL expression yourself:

```
$query = "SELECT user_id, username FROM user_db 
          WHERE email = '$loginEmail' AND password = SHA('$loginPassword')";
```

I really recommend using PDO and prepared queries instead of all the meticulous interpolation of variables into SQL.  That way, you don't have to worry about `mysql_real_escape_string()` or quotes or special characters.

```
$pdo = new PDO(...connection arguments...);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email = ? AND password = SHA(?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($loginEmail, $loginPassword));
```

See? You don't need to use single-quotes around the `?` parameter placeholders, you don't need to escape the variables you pass as parameters, and yet you don't need to worry about SQL Injection.

Also see my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies).

Also please read [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html) by fearless leader.

Comment: Thank you for the wealth of information, specifically for explanation of my problem and the valuable security related links, it is highly appreciated as a new PHP user!

Answer (score 0):

An E-mail address will be a string: are you quoting it in your SQL query?
Use quotes in the same way as you're using them for $loginPassword

```
$query = "SELECT user_id, username FROM user_db WHERE email = '$loginEmail' AND password = SHA('$loginPassword')";
```

or better still, use bind variables, as Bil Karwin's example shows

Comment: I will add the additional code to the original post, but I the e-mail address is being passed into a variable.